# wireless interface fails to raise

Tags: arch-linux, wifi

I've attempted to raise my wireless interface using `ip link set wlp2s2 up` and it is not raising. I'm running arch linux 32 on an IBM thinkpad r51 with an Intel PRO/Wireless 2200BG wireless card. I have the proper driver installed and enabled and I can discover wifi networks but when I try to connect to them it loops the authentication process.
output of d`mesg -T | grep -i wlp2s2`:

```
[Thu Dec 12 15:50:54 2019] ipw2200 0000:02:02.0 wlp2s2: renamed from eth0
[Thu Dec 12 15:51:06 2019] wlp2s2: Setting MAC to ee:96:e1:64:55:e9
[Thu Dec 12 15:52:32 2019] wlp2s2: Setting MAC to 00:0e:35:35:c9:39
[Thu Dec 12 15:52:33 2019] wlp2s2: Setting MAC to 2e:58:85:6c:fc:3c
[Thu Dec 12 15:53:39 2019] wlp2s2: Setting MAC to 1e:0a:0d:c0:04:ec
[Thu Dec 12 15:55:39 2019] wlp2s2: Setting MAC to 12:1e:7d:8c:5c:32
[Thu Dec 12 16:00:58 2019] wlp2s2: Setting MAC to ce:ec:55:26:38:a0
```

ouput of `journalctl -f`:

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2019-12-11 15:49:28 UTC. --
Dec 12 16:43:25 mikael NetworkManager[318]: <warn>  [1576169005.9104] device (wlp2s2): no secrets: User canceled the secrets request.
Dec 12 16:43:25 mikael NetworkManager[318]: <info>  [1576169005.9105] device (wlp2s2): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 12 16:43:25 mikael NetworkManager[318]: <info>  [1576169005.9251] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Dec 12 16:43:25 mikael NetworkManager[318]: <warn>  [1576169005.9460] device (wlp2s2): Activation: failed for connection 'Uniblab'
Dec 12 16:43:25 mikael NetworkManager[318]: <info>  [1576169005.9536] device (wlp2s2): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 12 16:43:25 mikael kernel: wlp2s2: Setting MAC to ae:dc:84:9c:76:97
Dec 12 16:43:26 mikael NetworkManager[318]: <warn>  [1576169006.0710] device (wlp2s2): set-hw-addr: new MAC address AE:DC:84:9C:76:97 not successfully set (scanning)
Dec 12 16:43:26 mikael NetworkManager[318]: <info>  [1576169006.1905] device (wlp2s2): supplicant interface state: inactive -> disabled
Dec 12 16:43:26 mikael NetworkManager[318]: <info>  [1576169006.2434] device (wlp2s2): supplicant interface state: disabled -> inactive
Dec 12 16:43:26 mikael wpa_supplicant[333]: wlp2s2: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
```

output of `ifconfig`

```
wlp2s2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether aa:89:89:1b:00:46  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Any tips or clues would be greatly appreciated

Comment: may you show us the output od `rfkill list` to see if your device is maybe soft blocked and of `ifconfig` to see the flags of your device?

Comment: rfkill list shows that it is neither soft blocked nor hard blocked and I've appended the output of ifconfig to the post.

Comment: your `wlp2s2` is up but not running; do you use a network manager and if yes which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had the same problem with my headless nas laptop and I learned the following:

If you have a WPA/WPA2 password/string it is not enough/not working to pass it over through the accesspoint/router blank via terminal for many, but mainly security reasons.

1.
You have to generate an encryption key out of the password and you can do it via wpa-supplicant f.e. `with wpa_passphrase your-ESSID your-wifi-passphrase | sudo tee /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`as describesudo pacman -S NetworkManagerd [here](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/connect-to-wi-fi-from-terminal-on-ubuntu-18-04-19-04-with-wpa-supplicant) or [here](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/connect-wifi-terminal-ubuntu-16-04/) and works on arch linux exact the same way. 
Btw. it doesn't matter where you store your wpa-supplicant file - just remember the path to it. binarym also told you the basic structure  in his answer.
(the generated wpa-supplicant key, not the wpa password itself is what is needed in the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration/Wireless))

---

2. If you got Internet connected f.e. via LAN cable you can `sudo pacman -S wifi-menu` and than execute `wifi-menu` that is the fastest way I found to connect to a password protected wifi from terminal and generate a wpa_supplicant key out of a password. It might be already installed.

---

3. The best way to connect via terminal via netctl because it is the most transparent way to connect to the wifi I found [here](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-setup-a-wifi-in-arch-linux-using-terminal), described as "the hard way" but as I found the most logical way and most easy to handle as follows and it should be already installed:

a) 
check the example folder with `ls /etc/netctl/examples`

b)
select one example profile that works for you and copy it to the netctl folder, in your case:

`sudo cp /etc/netctl/examples/wireless-wpa /etc/netctl/your_profile_name`

or

`sudo cp /etc/netctl/examples/wireless-wpa-static /etc/netctl/your_static_profile_name` - if you want a static ip address.

c) 
Edit your profile f.e. with vim or nano /etc/netctl/your_profile_name, add your password - blank or key by uncommenting what you need and save it with `ctrl + x` or at vim with `:wq`

d) 
and than just `netctl start your_profile_name` -
or stop it with `netctl stop your_profile_name` or to autostart it with `netctl enable your profile_name` - as simple as that.
(you may have to install netctl with sudo pacman -S netctl)

---

4.
If you decide to use/install a graphical interface like gnome
you can use NetworkManager (`sudo pacman -S NetworkManager`).

*I think my first two answers should already solve your issue - the others are more out of convenience because I personally like them more because I can remember them more easily.*

Answer (score 1):

Given the two following lines:

```
Dec 12 16:43:25 mikael NetworkManager[318]: <warn>  [1576169005.9104] device (wlp2s2): no secrets: User canceled the secrets request.
Dec 12 16:43:25 mikael NetworkManager[318]: <info>  [1576169005.9105] device (wlp2s2): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

I would tell that the network you're trying to connect to isn't an open one and you didn't configured any authentication for it in `wpa-supplicant` configuration file.

For `ip` to be successful, the underlying layers (aka `802.<whatever>`) should be working.
So, the steps are:

1. Configure the good secrets for `wpa-supplicant`.
2. Launch `wpa-supplicant`.
3. Up your interface.